# The attribute css is undefined for the annotation type FindBy

Tags: selenium

I am trying this automation testing using Selenium:

```
package pageobject;

import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebElement;
import org.openqa.selenium.support.FindBy;

public class loginpage {
    private WebDriver driver;

    @FindBy(css="div.mod-login-input-loginName>input")
    public WebElement txtUserName;
    @FindBy(css="div.mod-login-input-loginName>span")
    public WebElement lbUserNameError;
    @FindBy(css="div.mod-login-input-password>input[type=password]")
    public WebElement txtPassword;
    @FindBy(css="div.mod-login-input-password>span")
    public WebElement lbPasswordError;
    @FindBy(css="button.next-btn-primary")
    public WebElement btnLogin;
    @FindBy(css="div.next-feedback-toast")
    public WebElement pnlNotifier;
    @FindBy(css="div.next-feedback-toast .next-feedback-content")
    public WebElement lbNotification;

    public loginpage(WebDriver driver)
    {
        this.driver=driver;
        PageFactory.initElements(driver, this);
    }
}
```

I am receiving the following error message:

The attribute css is undefined for the annotation type FindBy

How can I resolve this?

Comment: Are you using any build tool ?

Comment: I used Eclipse @cruisepandey